# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set') while using WebDriverIO SharedStore service

Tags: typescript, automation, webdriver-io

I follow exactly this instruction from WebDriverIO about Shared Store Service https://webdriver.io/docs/shared-store-service/, for example:

Install it in package.json:

`npm install @wdio/shared-store-service --save-dev`

Add it to wdio configuration file:

```
// wdio.conf.js
export const config = {
    // ...
    services: ['shared-store'],
    // ...
};
```

But when I try to use it in my test, like this:

```
const companyUrl = await $('#companyUrl').getValue();
await browser.sharedStore.set('companyUrl', companyUrl)
```

I always get this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')`

So the `sharedStore` is not utilized. What am I still missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was, I have many wdio.conf files for different tests, and I placed `shared-store` in the wrong conf file.

After put it in the correct .conf file in which I need `shared-store`, I have no problem anymore, for example:

```
services: [
   ['chromedriver'],
   ['shared-store'],
],
```